# How to prevent event bubble

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app

This is the my lightning component i put onclick on  and inside of td i put onclick on checkbox. 
Problem :
When i click on checkbox the td controller js function is also called. i want at time one controller is called. for handling this one i use event.stopPropagation(). But it should not work. Please check.

```
<aura:component access="global">
<aura:attribute name="fields" type="Object[]" description="Data from strike_dataGrid" required="true"/>

<aura:attribute name="indexId" type="Integer" />
<aura:attribute name="sortFieldValue" type="String" description="Set during sort to determine sort order"/>
<aura:attribute name="isChecked" type="Boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="lstTickers" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="isBool" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="lstTrueCheckBoxes" type="List" />    
<aura:registerEvent name="navigate" type="c:SL_evt_DataTableCheck"/>

<aura:registerEvent name="cmpEvent" type="c:SL_evt_SObjectSelectionEvent"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="showDetail" type="c:SL_evt_ShowContactDetail"/>
<aura:attribute name="prevSelectedRow" type="Object" />     
<aura:registerEvent name="unSelectRow" type="c:SL_evt_UnselectRow"/>

<aura:handler event="c:SL_evt_getTheInterest" action="{!c.handleApplicationEvent}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

<tr>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="field" indexVar="index">
        <td  data-label="{!field.label}" style="{!if(field.dataType == 'ROWCHECKBOX', 'width:3.25rem', '')}" onclick="{!c.ShowContactDetail}" data-value="{!field.recordId}">

            <span Id='{!field.recordId}'  aura:id="value-output"  data-field="{!field.name}" data-value="{!field.recordId}" class="{!if(field.dataType != 'COMPONENT', 'slds-truncate', '')}" title="{!if(field.dataType == 'COMPONENT', '', field.value)}">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'BOOLEAN'}">
                    <ui:outputCheckbox value="{!field.value}" />
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'CURRENCY'}">
                    <ui:outputCurrency value="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'DATE'}">
                    <ui:outputDate value="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'DATETIME'}">
                    <ui:outputDateTime format="M/dd/yyyy H:mm a" value="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'EMAIL'}">
                    <ui:outputEmail value="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!or(field.dataType == 'NUMBER' , field.dataType == 'DOUBLE')}">
                    <ui:outputNumber value="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'PERCENT'}">
                    <ui:outputNumber value="{!field.value}"/>%
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'PHONE'}">
                    <ui:outputPhone value="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'URL'}">
                    <ui:outputURL value="{!field.value}" label="{!field.value}"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'DOWNLOADURL'}">
                    <a onclick="{!c.processClickedData}" id="{!field.value}">{!field.value}</a>
                </aura:if>

                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'STRING'}">
                     {!field.value}
              </aura:if>

                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'CUSTOMREFRENCE'}">
                    <a onclick="{!c.processClickedData}" id="{!field.referenceId}">{!field.value}</a>
                </aura:if>

                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'RELATEDICON'}">
                    <img src="{!field.value}" style="height:22px;"/>
                </aura:if>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!field.dataType == 'ROWCHECKBOX'}">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <label class="slds-checkbox">
                                <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkContact" value="{!field.value}"  text="{!field.recordId}" change="{!c.uncheckSelectAll}"/>
                                <span class="slds-checkbox--faux" /> 
                                <span class="slds-form-element__label"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </aura:if>
            </span>
        </td>
    </aura:iteration>
</tr>
```

JS Controller

```
ShowContactDetail: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('card first');
    var ctarget = event.currentTarget;
    var selectedRow = ctarget.parentNode;
    var unselectEvent = component.getEvent("unSelectRow");
    unselectEvent.setParams({
        "row": selectedRow
    });
    unselectEvent.fire();
    selectedRow.classList.add('selected');
    var id_str = ctarget.dataset.value;
    var cmpEvent = $A.get("e.c:SL_evt_ShowContactDetail");
    cmpEvent.setParams({
        "recId": id_str,
        "lstTickers": component.get('v.lstTickers')
    });
    cmpEvent.fire();
    event.stopPropagation();
},
uncheckSelectAll: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('checkbox');
    //event.stopPropagation();
    var rowCheck = component.find("checkContact").get('v.value');
    var rowId = component.find("checkContact");
    var selectedRecord = rowId.get('v.text');
    if (selectedRecord) {
        var cmpEvent = $A.get("e.c:SL_evt_SObjectSelectionEvent");
        cmpEvent.setParams({
            "selectedRecord": selectedRecord,
            "flag": rowId.get('v.value')
        });
        cmpEvent.fire();
    }
    var recId = component.find("checkContact").get('v.text');
    var varfields = component.get('v.fields');
    if (!rowCheck) {
        var EmailAddress = '';
        if (varfields && varfields[0] && varfields[0].email) EmailAddress = varfields[0].email;
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:SL_evt_DataTableCheck");
        evt.setParams({
            "isRowChecked": rowCheck,
            "emailAddressDeSelected": EmailAddress
        });
        evt.fire();
    } else {
        if (varfields && varfields[0] && varfields[0].email) {
            var EmailAddress = varfields[0].email;
            var evt = $A.get("e.c:SL_evt_DataTableCheck");
            evt.setParams({
                "emailAddressSelected": EmailAddress
            });
            evt.fire();
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

If you call event.stopPropagation(), it will work. Here's a small demo that proves that it works:

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="log" type="List" default="[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="rows" type="List"
                    default="['Row 1','Row 2','Row 3']" />
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.rows}" var="row">
                <tr>
                    <td onclick="{!c.td}">
                        <a onclick="{!c.link}">{!row} Link</a>
                        {!row} Click Area
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.log}" var="item">
        <div>{!item}</div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    td: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.log(component, new Date().getTime()+": Td Area Clicked")
    },
    link: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.log(component, new Date().getTime()+": Nested Link Clicked")
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```

---

```
({
    log: function(component, message) {
        var log = component.get("v.log");
        log.push(message);
        component.set("v.log", log);
    }
})
```

---

Note that you didn't include processClickedDat function, so we can't really help you beyond this. Just make sure that the event's propagation is being stopped by calling event.stopPropagation().