# Button inside a whole clickable Lightning component div

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to have entire div clickable except for small portion of where button is? What is the right way to do it? With current solution below, it fires both events.

```
<div onclick="{!c.handleClick}">
    <div>
        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:clear"
                              alternativeText="Foo"
                              variant="bare"
                              onclick="{!c.handleButtonClick}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you change the onclick method for the button to just return false

Comment: @Eric Won't work, but you're on the right path.

Comment: Since my previous answer went unaccepted.... here we go again.

Comment: @sfdcfox figures. Was just shooting from hip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your onclick handler, if you want to stop event bubbling, call the method stopPropagation on the event parameter. Your onclick handler would look like this:

```
handleButtonClick: function(component, event, helper) {
    // ... other code here ...
    event.stopPropagation();
},
```

You can read more about it in [Handling Bubbled or Captured Component Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_bubbling.htm). A full copy-paste example can be found on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/218478).